# append dynamic 'div's inside dynamic 'div's using dynamic id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I create 110 dynamic div, and 11 container dynamic div, each 10 div of 110 I put them in One container dynamic div 11, then I append the first div of 11 to div that has "allEl" id, this is my code:

```
var index = 0;
var divContener; 
for (i = 0; i < 110; i++) {

                if (i % 9 == 0) {
                    index++;
                    alert(index);
                    divContener = $("<div> </div");
                    divContener.attr('id', 'd' + index);
                }

                $('#d' + index).append("<div  id='" + i + "'><a href=''><img src='" + smallImageArray[i] + "'/></a></div>");
                $('#' + i).append("</br> Rate);
            }
            document.getElementById("#allEl").innerHTML = $("#d" + 1);

              <div id="allEl">
                <h1 id="carsCategory">All Cars</h1>
             </div>
```

the problem is that the container div doesn't append to div that has "allEl" id,
What is the problem?

Comment: Please start by fixing your indentation and string delimiters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div id="allEl">
    <h1 id="carsCategory">All Cars</h1>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var index = 0;
    var divContener;
    var allElem=$("#allEl");
    for (var i = 0; i < 110; i++) {
        if (i % 9 == 0) {
            index++;
            divContener = $("<div></div>");
            divContener.attr('id', 'd' + index);
            allElem.append(divContener);
        }
        $('#d' + index).append("<div  id='" + i + "'><a href=''><img src='" + smallImageArray[i] + "'/></a></div>");
        $('#' + i).append("</br> Rate");
    }
    allElem.append($("#d" + 1));
</script>
```

I hope this is what you were trying to achieve..